# Turning keywords into lists in python dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've extracted key words from a different column to make a new column (hard skills) that looks like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNOIK.png)

But I want to make each key word into a list format within the "hards skills" column.
For example, for the 1st row of "hard skills" column, my desired outcome would be:

['Python Programming', 'Machine Learning', 'Data Analysis'...]

instead of

Python Programming,Machine Learning,Data Analysis...

This is how I filtered the key words out into the new "hard skills" column.

#Filter and make new column for hard skills
hard_skills = ['Python Programming', 'Statistics', 'Statistical Hypothesis Testing','Data Cleansing', 'Tensorflow', 'Machine Learning', 'Data Analysis','Data Visualization', 'Cloud Computing', 'R Programming', 'Data Science','Computer Programming', 'Deep Learning', 'Data Analysis', 'SQL', 'Regression Analysis', 'Algorithms', 'JavaScript', 'Python']

def get_hard_skills(skills):
return_hard_skills = ""
for hard_skill in hard_skills:
if skills.find(hard_skill) >= 0:
if return_hard_skills == "":
return_hard_skills = hard_skill
else:
return_hard_skills = return_hard_skills + "," + hard_skill
if return_hard_skills == "":
return ('not found')
else:
return return_hard_skills

course_name_skills['hard skills'] = ""

#loop through data frame to get hard skills

for i in range(0,len(course_name_skills)-1): #every single line of the data science courses
skills = course_name_skills.loc[i,"skills"]
if not isNaN(skills): #if not empty
course_name_skills.loc[i,"hard skills"] = get_hard_skills(skills)

course_name_skills = course_name_skills.replace('not found',np.NaN)
only_hardskills = course_name_skills.dropna(subset=['hard skills'])

Is there a way I could change the code that filtered the data frame for key words? Or is there a more efficient way?

I tried strip.() or even tried my luck with

```
return_hard_skills = "[" + return_hard_skills + "," + hard_skill + "]"
```

But it didn't come through.

[Dataframe with original column]

[image: 1]

[random, but needed, true or false table generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC6gD.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. First thing: Images != Code. Please post code as code.

Comment: @Lauren, also, can you share a sample of the column where do you exract the keywords ?

Comment: @abokey yep, just added a pic at the end of my post

Comment: remove screenshots and paste the code as plain text

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, there is no need for functions and/or loops here since you can use [**`pandas.Series.str.join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) to get your expected column/output :

```
course_name_skills["hard skills"]= course_name_skills["skills"].str.join(",")
```

*NB: The line above assumes that the column `hard skills` holds lists, otherwise (if strings) use this :*

```
course_name_skills["hard skills"]= (
                                    course_name_skills["skills"]
                                        .str.strip("[]")
                                        .replace({"'": "", "\s+": ""}, regex=True)
                                    )
```

Comment: just gave this a go, but it turned all my values in the hard skills column to NaN

Comment: Which code ? Anyway, can you `print(course_name_skills.sample(5).to_dict("list"))` and share it in your post ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['skills'] = df['hard skills'].str.split(',').apply(
    lambda skills: [skill.strip() for skill in skills]
)
```

And if you want to add filtering:

```
skills = list(set(df['skills'].sum()))
for skill in skills:
  df[skill] = df['skills'].apply(lambda x: skill in x)

df.loc[df['Data Analysis']==True]['course_name']
```

Comment: I tried this but it just changed both columns to [Python Programming, Machine Learning...] etc

Comment: Is there a way to just keep the key words in the original (skills) column instead of filtering and making a new column?

Comment: Perhaps start with uploading the dataframe again.  This code only changes `df['skills']`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by filtering. The question at the moment reads 'my ideal outcome is a list'.  So the answer creates the list by splitting the string in each row.  Can you edit your question with what you're trying to filter?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't too clear in my post. I meant to change the values within the hard skills column to a "list-like" format, so each cell is in square-brackets and each key word is in ''.

Comment: About filtering, I was suggesting if we could eliminate the non-key words from the original column (skills), instead of filtering and extracting these key words into a new column (now called 'hard skills').

Comment: made an addition to remove the whitespaces from around the words

Comment: thank you, but it says 'strip' not defined?

Comment: typo, should be in skills

Comment: for a moment it converted into a true or false table for each hard skill for each job (which is what I need anyways, attached screenshot above), it didn't change the formatting of the skills but now it says 'float' object is not iterable?

Comment: one of your rows has a number not some text